# SSL Timeout in Drupal's Akamai Module

Tags: drupal, soap, akamai

I have a client using the Drupal Akamai module to manage their site's caching. The client reports the following group of errors happen occasionally when a certain content type is deleted, however, I suspect that it is not limited to a specific content type.

`warning: SoapClient::__doRequest: SSL: connection timeout in /path/to/akamai/akamai.class.inc on line 85`

`warning: SoapClient::__doRequest: SSL: Failed to enable crypto in /path/to/akamai/akamai.class.inc on line 85`

`warning: SoapClient::__doRequest: SSL: connect() failed: Unspecified error in /path/to/akamai/akamai.class.inc on line 85`

The referenced line is a call to a method defined in the SoapClient's wsdl

`$response = $ccuapi->purgeRequest($name, $pwd, $network, $opt, $uris);`

I've searched high and low for why this may be happening. Although I've learned a great deal hunting this one down, I'm no soap expert. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might get a faster answer on the Drupal Answers Stack Exchange site. Sounds like an issue specific to that Drupal Module. Off the cuff I would start narrowing the problem by manually browsing and submitting a sample request, then when you've got an idea look into that $ccuapi object to see what's up. May be SSL related as Akamai has a whole song and dance they do on that subject.

Comment: Related: [OPENSSL file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14078182/55075).

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue might be proxy connection you are using. Your system not able to establish connection to akamai server to call akamai service call. 
I too faced same issue but after adding proxy it got resolved. 
Try to add these property using java.

```
 System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "your proxt ip ");
 System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "proxy port number");
```

or else download certificate named as "gte_global_root.der" and add to your security keystore