# How do I troubleshoot 'SSL: crypto enabling timeout' error?

Tags: php, ssl, odoo

I've been accessing Odoo regularly for months via the XML-RPC API. I use a php script I wrote that makes use of [darkaonline/ripcord](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/Ripcord) library.

All of a sudden, in the last day or so, I have been seeing this error in my logs:

> production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message
>   'file_get_contents(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout' in
>   app/vendor/darkaonline/ripcord/src/Ripcord/Client/Transport/Stream.php:59

Nothing has changed on my server in the last few days, so I'm wondering if anything has changed with Odoo that might be causing this. I am access an ODOO ONLINE instance, meaning, I do not host it, it's hosted by Odoo. It's using `Odoo 10.saas~14+e (Enterprise Edition)`.

My server is running `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic x86_64)` and using PHP version: `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2016 13:00:37)`.

Does anyone have any idea what this error means or why it suddenly started occurring? I have no idea where to being troubleshooting this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14078318/1207049

Comment: @marekful, can you explain a bit more? What does this mean? Did the Odoo server suddenly update their SSL version and my PHP script is using now using the wrong version? If you could offer a more detailed explanation that would really be helpful. I see the question you referenced is very relevant, but I don't know enough to connect all the pieces.

Comment: I linked this in so as to possibly having some clues. It's worth to give a try checking things like explicitly specifying sslv3 wiht cURL or playing with cipher algo settings.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do that. I'm not using curl. I'm using that Ripcord library I linked to which uses `file_get_contents`. I'm not sure where I would attempt to make any of these configuration changes.

Comment: @marekful, I was able to get the Ripcord library to use curl and use v3 ssl. When it attempts to make a call now, I get an error: `error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`. Any idea what would cause this?