# How to include php page from different website to current website?

Tags: php, ssl, url, cross-domain

I have a created a domain but all the functions and classes of that domain is to be stored on another domain. but i am unable to get the page using include or require method. I am getting the following error:

> Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: Failed to enable crypto in /domain.com/includes/functions.php on line 3 Warning: include_once(https:/other_domain.com/access.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /domain.com/includes/functions.php on line 3 Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'otherdomain.com/access.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /domain.com/includes/functions.php on line 3

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting on your new domain? I'd be curious to see what errors come up when you do try include or require.

Comment: Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: Failed to enable crypto in /domain.com/includes/functions.php on line 3

Warning: include_once(https:/other_domain.com/access.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: operation failed in /domain.com/includes/functions.php on line 3

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'otherdomain.com/access.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /domain.com/includes/functions.php on line 3

Answer (score 1):

The crypto error leads me to think this may be an issue with your SSL:
[OPENSSL file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078182/openssl-file-get-contents-failed-to-enable-crypto)