# set_time_limit and file_get_contents error

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

[image: photo]

I bought a ready-made script online. And I uploaded a hosting to it on the internet. but when I open the site it gives this error. What should I do?

Comment: Contact the seller or put your code here to hope have help

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems that you have:

## 1. set_time_limit disabled

[set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) is a PHP function defined in php.ini. It is probable that in your php.ini, you have this disabled. Try

```
print_r(ini_get('disable_functions'));
```

Do you see this function among the results? If so, open php.ini and change the setting of `disable_functions` to no longer contain this function.

## 2. Undefined index: nick

Your code tries to reference the item of an associative array called 'nick', but it does not exist. This could be a logical error or a technical error. You will need to open image.php and look at line 7 to see what the intention of the code is.

## 3. SSL operation failed with code 1.

You will need to set up your SSL, see [file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1, Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto)

## 4. Failed to enable Crypto

It is either due to the lack of a proper SSL setting or a version mismatch. See [OPENSSL file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078182/openssl-file-get-contents-failed-to-enable-crypto)

## 5. Operation failed

The consequence of former errors.

## 6. Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean

You are calling `$someresource->find()`, but `$someresource` is `boolean` instead of an object that would have such a value.

[file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns `false` on failure. Maybe your code expects it to return proper data and fails to initialize an object if it returns false.

**If you need further help** you will need to provide more details, like the code that you are running.